# How to extract text and tag attributes from xml using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, xml, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the texts along with width, height, top , left and page number from below xml and append it to a dataframe.

```
   <page number="1" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
       <fontspec id="0" size="21" family="MOFZXD+AvenirNext-DemiBold" color="#231f20"/>
       <fontspec id="1" size="25" family="MOFZXD+MyriadPro-Regular" color="#231f20"/>

       <text top="375" left="708" width="168" height="33" font="0"><b>LISTING # 1131</b></text>
       <text top="1049" left="657" width="92" height="32" font="1">1.03 +/- </text>
       <text top="1049" left="750" width="51" height="35" font="1">Acre</text>
       <text top="1089" left="657" width="178" height="27" font="2">Tax Map and Parcel:</text>
   </page>


   <page number="2" position="absolute" top="0" left="0" height="1188" width="918">
       <fontspec id="6" size="23" family="MOFZXD+Baskerville" color="#57585a"/>
       <fontspec id="7" size="10" family="LGVTJF+Avenir-Roman" color="#231f20"/>
       <text top="827" left="681" width="107" height="33" font="6">Andy Cox </text>
       <text top="861" left="681" width="186" height="17" font="7">COMMERCIAL SALES SPECIALIST</text>
   </page>
```

I've tried using the below code, but the result contains only duplicate values.

```
for message in soup.findAll('page'):
    page_number = re.findall(r'number=\"(\d*?)\"', str(message))[0]
    for text in soup.findAll('text'):
        content = text.text

        #print(font_value)
        height_value = re.findall(r'height="(\d*?)"',str(text))[0]
        left_value = re.findall(r'left="(\d*?)"',str(text))[0]
        top_value = re.findall(r'top="(\d*?)"',str(text))[0]
        width_value = re.findall(r'top="(\d*?)"',str(text))[0]

        df = df.append({'Page Number':page_number,'Content':content,'Top':top_value,'Left':left_value,'Width':width_value,'Height':height_value},ignore_index=True)
```

RESULT

```
    Page Number Content     Top Left    Width   Height
1   LISTING  #1131  375 708 375 33
1   1.03 +/-    1049    657 1049    32
1   Acre    1049    750 1049    35
1   Tax Map and Parcel: 1089    657 1089    27
2   Andy Cox    827 681 107 33
2   COMMERCIAL SALES SPECIALIST 861 681 186 17
```

Comment: You should just find the text tags and then access their attributes. I’m not sure I understand what you’re currently doing. Also, BeautifulSoup is really better suited to parsing HTML. I recommend `lxml` for all your xml parsing needs.

Comment: Is `RESULT` tour **expected** result?

Comment: Would be good if you shared some representative data, too. Please see: [mcve].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - there is example markup in the question.

Comment: @wwii Yes I saw, I just wanted to make sure that the format is consistent.

Comment: @wwii Forgot to add that the XML in the answer certainly isn't complete, since it's missing a root tag.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` parses the example just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to Find the tags you want and extract the info from the tags.

```
import operator
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
whatiwant = operator.itemgetter('top','left','width','height')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
for page in soup.findAll('page'):
    for t in page.findAll('text'):
        print(page['number'], t.text, whatiwant(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

I opted to use BeautifulSoup to parse XML for once, it worked just fine. I added a root tag to your data so my IDE would stop complaining.

**Code:**

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

col_names = ['page_number', 'elem_text', 'elem_top', 'elem_left', 'elem_width', 'elem_height']

with open('../resources/page_text_xml_data.xml') as file_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(file_in, features='xml')

row_dicts = []

for curr_page in soup.find('root').find_all('page', recursive=False):
    curr_page_num = curr_page['number']
    for curr_text_elem in curr_page.find_all('text', recursive=False):
        row_dicts.append(
            {'page_number': curr_page_num, 'elem_text': curr_text_elem.text.strip(), 'elem_top': curr_text_elem['top'],
             'elem_left': curr_text_elem['left'], 'elem_width': curr_text_elem['width'],
             'elem_height': curr_text_elem['height']})

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(row_dicts)
```

**DataFrame contents:**

```
      page_number  elem_text                      elem_top    elem_left    elem_width    elem_height
--  -------------  ---------------------------  ----------  -----------  ------------  -------------
 0              1  LISTING # 1131                      375          708           168             33
 1              1  1.03 +/-                           1049          657            92             32
 2              1  Acre                               1049          750            51             35
 3              1  Tax Map and Parcel:                1089          657           178             27
 4              2  Andy Cox                            827          681           107             33
 5              2  COMMERCIAL SALES SPECIALIST         861          681           186             17
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)